# Invalid register options "value" must be an object hapi-auth-jwt2

Tags: authentication, jwt, hapi.js

I'm getting a strange error `Invalid register options "value" must be an object` whenever I try to run my hapi server. I can't seem to figure out the issue. This is my code:

```
await server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt2'), (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            server.auth.strategy('jwt', 'jwt', {
                key: secretKey,
                verifyOptions: { algorithms: ['HS256'] }
            });

            glob.sync('api/**/routes/*.js', {
                root: __dirname
            }).forEach(file => {
                const route = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
                server.route(route);
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

I've also tried this and I'm still getting the error:

```
const options = {
            key: secretKey,
            verifyOptions: { algorithms: ['HS256'] }
        };

await server.register({
            register: require('hapi-auth-jwt2'),
            options
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            // We're giving the strategy both a name
            // and scheme of 'jwt'
            server.auth.strategy('jwt', 'jwt', {
                key: secretKey,
                verifyOptions: { algorithms: ['HS256'] }
            });

            glob.sync('api/**/routes/*.js', {
                root: __dirname
            }).forEach(file => {
                const route = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
                server.route(route);
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
```

Does anyone have any idea what this error is about? Is it just that `hapi-auth-jwt2` is not up to date with Hapi v17? If so I've tried changing my dependency version to `salzhrani/hapi-auth-jwt2#v-17` as mentioned in https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/pull/249

I've also tried the temporary fix in https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/issues/248 with no luck.

Comment: Could you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are not providing a function for the [validateFunc](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/the-current-state-of-implementation-and-planning-for-esmodules-a4ecb2aac07a) option.